# Trying to find sporadic audio source in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For some reason, my Yahoo email tab sporadically plays audio from the beginning of an ad.  The audio is definitely coming from this tab because it shows the small audio icon while it plays.  I'm looking for some help using Chrome's Developer Tools.  When I hear the audio clip, I have the Developer Tools open and I reference the [Network] tab, but I don't see any audio files referenced.  I think it might be part of JavaScript.  I'm looking for some guidance on how to isolate the source of the audio.  Yahoo support was zero help.

Comment: Try to set a [media event breakpoint](https://puu.sh/CJHXg/62099f0a66.png) in the Sources panel of devtools.

Comment: Done.  What will happen when an audio plays?

Comment: The relevant code should be paused so you can inspect it. You need to have devtools open in that tab beforehand, with those events checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow these Steps to get the URL of the audio**

1. Open the web page
2. Inspect the web page
3. Go to the `Sources` tab
4. Expand the `Event Listener Breakpoints` dropdown
5. Expand the `Media` dropdown
6. Mark the `playing` checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @wOxxOm:

In DevTools, Sources, Event Listener Breakpoints, set breakpoints on all Media then wait till the sound is played or trigger it if you can. Then you should get some minified JS code, which you can pretty-print for easier reading, although the code is still minified and thus obfuscated so you have to kind of guess what it's doing. In my case, the code stopped on an `ended` event, but not on `play`. Still, I was able to find the code that actually played the sound - it went something like:

```js
                (h = e.play()) ? h.then(()=>{
                    a.Pa.info`Playing ${e.src}`;
                    a.ta = !0
                }
```

and hovering over `src` (I could also have inspected `e` in that context to find `src`) showed me the URI for an mp3 that was the sound I was looking for! Breakpoints set on `WebAudio` did not work in this case - maybe it depends on the type of audio media being played? But I found the mp3 I was looking for! (Not saying what it was, but it was a very short clip - about 2 seconds - and as I understand it, samples below a certain length are not copyrightable, although I'm not 100% sure about that, so beware - as it is, I intend to use it for a personal, non-commercial project.